# Hide North Panel if Nothing to Show with JQuery UI Layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-layout

I have a simple layout with north and center:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body>
        <div id="north-main-div">
        </div>
        <div id="center-main-div">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And JavaScript which makes a hideable Northpanel.

```
topMainLayout = $('body').layout({
    name : 'bodyLayout',
    north__paneSelector : '#north-main-div',
    center__paneSelector : '#center-main-div',
    north__resizable : false
});
```

I would like to achieve that the whole north area is invisible including the toggler if nothing (no content) is within the `north-main-id`. Currently the toggler will show even if nothing is to show there.

I would appreciate any hint for solving the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the proper way, but it worked for me.

I juste check with if it is empty and call the hide function.

```
topMainLayout = $('body').layout({
    name : 'bodyLayout',
    north__paneSelector : '#north-main-div',
    center__paneSelector : '#center-main-div',
    north__resizabele : false
}); 
if (!$.trim( $('#north-main-div').html() ).length) {
        topMainLayout.hide("north");
}
```